# How to add div inside other div in gallery script using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a `<div>` inside a `<div class="ad-image">` - How can it be done?

Gallery script is here: http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/

This is the way I created `<div class="ad-image">`

```
var img_container = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('ad-image');
```

Comment: jQuery has a good documentation about DOM manipulation methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ I suggest you have a look at it. Why is everyone asking questions that can be easily solved by looking at the documentation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var img_container = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('ad-image'),
    new_div = $("<div></div>");

img_container.append(new_div);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

```
$(".ad-image").append("<div>New div here</div>")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<div class="ad-image" />').appendTo($('div'));
```

Working jsfiddle: [JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/cUYMQ/)